# I am facing an issue with string and null characters in C++.Null character is behaving differently

Tags: c++, string, null, c-strings

I am facing an issue with string and null characters in C++.
When I am writing '\0' in between the string and printing the string then I am getting only part before '\0' but on the other hand when I am taking string as input then changing any index as '\0' then it is printing differently. Why is it so and why the sizeof(string) is 32 in both the cases
Code is below for reference. Please help.

First code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s = "he\0llo";

cout<<s.length()<<"\n";
cout<<s<<endl;
cout<<sizeof(s)<<"\n";
}
```

output of First code:

```
2\n
he\n
32\n
```

Second code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s;
cin>>s;
s[1] = '\0';
cout<<s<<"\n";
cout<<s.length()<<"\n";
cout<<sizeof(s)<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

output of second code:

```
hllo\n
5\n
32\n
```

Below is the image for your reference.
[image]

Comment: `sizeof(s)` is the size of the `std::string` object itself and has no relation to the amount of data in the actual string.

Comment: Change `string s = "he\0llo";` to `auto hello = "he\0llo"; string s(hello, hello + sizeof hello - 1);`

Answer (score 4):

[`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)'s implicit `const CharT*` constructors and assignment operator don't know the exact length of the string argument. Instead, it only knows that this is a `const char*` and is forced to assume that the string will be **null-terminated**, and thus computes the length using [`std::char_traits::length(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) (effectively [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)).

As a result, constructing a `std::string` object with an expression like:

```cpp
std::string s = "he\0llo";
```

will compute `2` as the length of the string, since it assumes the first `\0` character is the null terminator for the string, whereas your second example of:

```cpp
s[1] = '\0';
```

is simply *adding* a null character into an already constructed string -- which does not change the size of the string.

If you want to construct a string with a null character in the middle, you can't let it compute the length of the string for you. Instead, you will have to construct the `std::string` and give it the length in some other way. This could either by done with the `string(const char*, size_t)` constructor, or with an iterator pair if this is an array:

```cpp
// Specify the length manually
std::string s{"he\0llo",6};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n6K4c4E4z)</kbd>

```
// Using iterators to a different container (such as an array)
const char c_str[] = "he\0llo";
std::string s{std::begin(c_str), std::end(c_str)};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MsM6494v9)</kbd>

**Note:** `sizeof(s)` is telling you the size of `std::string` class itself in bytes for your implementation of the standard library. This does not tell you the length of the contained string -- which can be determined from either `s.length()` or `s.size()`.

Answer (score 3):

As of c++14, there is an option to specify quoted strings as a std::string by using std::literals. This prevents conversion of an array of chars to string which automatically stops at the first nul character.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    string s = "he\0llo"s;   // This initializes s to the full 6 char sequence.
    cout << s.length() << "\n";
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << sizeof(s) << "\n";  // prints size of the s object, not the size of its contents
}
```

Results:

```
6
hello
28
```

Comment: Huh, it never occurred to me that the string literal operator could be used for this purpose. Good answer!